# Norm of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the norm of

$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] = [a_0 + a_1\zeta + ...+a_{l-2}\zeta^{l-2} : a_i \in \mathbb{Z}],$$

for $(l \leq 19)$ prime, and $\zeta$ root of unity,  so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is UFD.

It is easy when $l=3$, $(a+b\zeta)(a+b\bar{\zeta}) = a^2 - ab+ b^2$

Comment: Not sure it is very easy : for a fixed element, would you not need to find the minimal polynomial or the conjugates of that element? For $l=3$ the conjugates were easy to find, but for larger $l$ this may be an issue.

Comment: Do you mean norm of an element, perhaps? (Note that UFDs may not be a Euclidean domain and so there may not be a Euclidean function)

Comment: @daruma, see [Field norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm)

Comment: For $l=5$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24840/finding-the-norm-in-the-cyclotomic-field-mathbbqe2-pi-i-5. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175118/how-to-compute-efficiently-the-norm-of-a-cyclotomic-integer